# How to Shift Counter Column in Sas with Conditions

Tags: sas, counter

I am having an issue with shifting a counter Column down in SAS by One as it wont meet my conditions.

```
`data Distinct_Member1;
set Distinct_Member;
by Member_ID startyear;
retain Count 0;
if first.Member_ID then Count = 0;
if (Purchased_Fruit in ('Apples') and Quantity_Purchased not in ('None') and group not in 
('Females')) then Count = Count + 1;
if (Purchased_Fruit not in ('Apples') OR Quantity_Purchased in ('None') OR group in 
('Females')) then Count = Count + 1
run;`
```

This is the code for the original Counter but now I want to Shift the Counter by 1 down as below

| Member_Id | Purchased_Fruit | Group | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | Female | 1 |
| 1 | Apples | Female | 2 |
| 1 | Apples | Female | 3 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 1 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 2 |
| 2 | Bananas | Female | 0 |
| 2 | Bananas | Female | 0 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 1 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 2 |
| 3 | Apples | Male | 0 |
| 4 | Pears | Female | 0 |
| 4 | Apples | Female | 1 |
| 4 | Oranges | Female | 0 |

And this is what I am looking to achieve with the Count_Shift Column

| Member_Id | Purchased_Fruit | Group | Count | Count_Shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | Female | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | Apples | Female | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Apples | Female | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | Bananas | Female | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | Bananas | Female | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | Apples | Female | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Apples | Male | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Pears | Female | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Apples | Female | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | Oranges | Female | 0 | 1 |

I have tried a combination of this and lag functions however I never seem to have the desired result. Any help or direction with how to achieve the Count_Shift column is appreciated! Thank you.

```
data Distinct_Member2;
set Distinct_Member1;
by Member_ID;

retain Count_Shift 0; if first.Member_ID then Count_Shift = 0;
else if Count >0 then Count_Shift = Count - 1;
run;
```

Comment: Your new variable is losing information that the old variable had.  There is no way to tell if the FIRST observation for an member met the criteria or not since in both cases you appear to want a value of 0.

Comment: Your code is referencing a variable QUATIFY_PURCHASED that is not in the dataset.

Comment: Cannot get your code to produce those values COUNT (if I ignore the missing variable).

Comment: Calculating COUNT_SHIFT from a COUNT value that already exists is just a simple use of the LAG() function.  Just remember 1) run the LAG() function on every observation 2) use BY group processing to know when to overwrite the result with your default value for the first observation for a member.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit confusing because the data you showed doesn't fit with the code you showed. If your goal is for Count_Shift to be, in effect, a lag within Member_ID, you can do that like:

```
data Distinct_Member2;
  set Distinct_Member1;
  by Member_ID;
  Count_Shift=lag(Count) ;
  if first.Member_ID then Count_Shift=0 ;
run;
```